# looping a javascript Object Array (inside another object)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to loop an javascript object array

This is my object `response`:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p3288namrojte20g\"",
 "summary": "pedicura",
 "updated": "2019-05-01T14:25:51.642Z",
 "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Cordoba",
 "accessRole": "owner",
 "defaultReminders": [
  {
   "method": "popup",
   "minutes": 30
  }
 ],
 "nextSyncToken": "CJCLqtvE-uECEJCLqtvE-uECGAU=",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3113441344690000\"",
   "id": "hb6me2h********1dun5rs10",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=aGI2bWUyaGFvaGtqbWI4bXYxZHVuNXJzMTAgZTYyMXJtMD********Zw",
   "created": "2019-05-01T14:12:08.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-05-01T14:24:32.345Z",
   "summary": "Prueba de: Pedicura en sala 2-x",
   "description": "x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?",
   "creator": {
    "email": "guit----@gmail.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "pedicura",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-08T21:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-08T23:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "iCalUID": "hb6me2ha----s10@google.com",
   "sequence": 2,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "aleja----it@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    },
    {
     "email": "j----d@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3113441378884000\"",
   "id": "tv**0nbhkt**47la0k",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dHZmOTQwbmJoa3Q3cnJvYjJsMW00N2xhMGsgZTYyMXJtM*****",
   "created": "2019-05-01T14:18:53.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-05-01T14:24:49.442Z",
   "summary": "Prueba de: Pedicura en sala 2-x",
   "description": "x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?",
   "creator": {
    "email": "guit----@gmail.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "pedicura",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-07T21:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-07T23:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "iCalUID": "tvf940nbhk----m47la0k@google.com",
   "sequence": 2,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "ale---it@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    },
    {
     "email": "j--d@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3113441503284000\"",
   "id": "tqhje1kd*****0",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dHFoamUxa2Q0MG51M2Q3cGd2b2xlOGRqODAgZTYyMX*****",
   "created": "2019-05-01T14:25:51.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-05-01T14:25:51.642Z",
   "summary": "Prueba de",
   "description": "x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?",
   "creator": {
    "email": "guit----@gmail.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "prueba",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-04-26T21:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-04-26T23:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "iCalUID": "tqh*****7pgvole8dj80@google.com",
   "sequence": 0,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "-it@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    },
    {
     "email": "-aud@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to loop items (inside of body) and I've tryed something like this:

```
var dataStr = JSON.stringify(response);
var dataPrs = JSON.parse(dataStr);
var dataList = JSON.stringify(dataPrs.items);
dataStr = JSON.stringify(dataList);
dataPrs = JSON.parse(dataStr);
dataListPrs.forEach( console.log(dataPrs.htmlLink) );
```

and also:

```
cons items = data.items;
items.forEach(x => console.log(x.htmlLink))
```

and also:

```
var dataStr = JSON.stringify(response);
var dataPrs = JSON.parse(dataStr);
var body = dataPrs.body.items;
console.log("body", body);
const items = response.items;
console.log("items", items);
items.forEach(x => console.log(x.htmlLink));
```

but `items` is always `undefined`

Comment: of course items is always undefined since this `data` entity is never declared anywhere?

Comment: I put data but it was response

Comment: I tried to parse and stringfy twice because I'm lost

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `forEach()` to get the **htmlLinks** from the json object like below-

```js
let obj =  {"kind":"calendar#events","etag":"\"p3288namrojte20g\"","summary":"pedicura","updated":"2019-05-01T14:25:51.642Z","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Cordoba","accessRole":"owner","defaultReminders":[{"method":"popup","minutes":30}],"nextSyncToken":"CJCLqtvE-uECEJCLqtvE-uECGAU=","items":[{"kind":"calendar#event","etag":"\"3113441344690000\"","id":"hb6me2h********1dun5rs10","status":"confirmed","htmlLink":"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=aGI2bWUyaGFvaGtqbWI4bXYxZHVuNXJzMTAgZTYyMXJtMD********Zw","created":"2019-05-01T14:12:08.000Z","updated":"2019-05-01T14:24:32.345Z","summary":"Prueba de: Pedicura en sala 2-x","description":"x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?","creator":{"email":"guit----@gmail.com"},"organizer":{"email":"e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com","displayName":"pedicura","self":true},"start":{"dateTime":"2019-05-08T21:00:00-03:00","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"},"end":{"dateTime":"2019-05-08T23:00:00-03:00","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"},"iCalUID":"hb6me2ha----s10@google.com","sequence":2,"attendees":[{"email":"aleja----it@gmail.com","responseStatus":"needsAction"},{"email":"j----d@gmail.com","responseStatus":"needsAction"}],"reminders":{"useDefault":true}},{"kind":"calendar#event","etag":"\"3113441378884000\"","id":"tv**0nbhkt**47la0k","status":"confirmed","htmlLink":"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dHZmOTQwbmJoa3Q3cnJvYjJsMW00N2xhMGsgZTYyMXJtM*****","created":"2019-05-01T14:18:53.000Z","updated":"2019-05-01T14:24:49.442Z","summary":"Prueba de: Pedicura en sala 2-x","description":"x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?","creator":{"email":"guit----@gmail.com"},"organizer":{"email":"e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com","displayName":"pedicura","self":true},"start":{"dateTime":"2019-05-07T21:00:00-03:00","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"},"end":{"dateTime":"2019-05-07T23:00:00-03:00","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"},"iCalUID":"tvf940nbhk----m47la0k@google.com","sequence":2,"attendees":[{"email":"ale---it@gmail.com","responseStatus":"needsAction"},{"email":"j--d@gmail.com","responseStatus":"needsAction"}],"reminders":{"useDefault":true}},{"kind":"calendar#event","etag":"\"3113441503284000\"","id":"tqhje1kd*****0","status":"confirmed","htmlLink":"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dHFoamUxa2Q0MG51M2Q3cGd2b2xlOGRqODAgZTYyMX*****","created":"2019-05-01T14:25:51.000Z","updated":"2019-05-01T14:25:51.642Z","summary":"Prueba de","description":"x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?","creator":{"email":"guit----@gmail.com"},"organizer":{"email":"e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com","displayName":"prueba","self":true},"start":{"dateTime":"2019-04-26T21:00:00-03:00","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"},"end":{"dateTime":"2019-04-26T23:00:00-03:00","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"},"iCalUID":"tqh*****7pgvole8dj80@google.com","sequence":0,"attendees":[{"email":"-it@gmail.com","responseStatus":"needsAction"},{"email":"-aud@gmail.com","responseStatus":"needsAction"}],"reminders":{"useDefault":true}}]}
    
obj['items'].forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
  if(item.hasOwnProperty('htmlLink')){
     console.log(item.htmlLink)  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sunny but i still get "TypeError: obj.items is undefined"

Comment: @AlejandroLevit could you please see my edit again?

Comment: is about the dot? i'm using "obj['items']" but it still shows that error.

Comment: seems your response is in **string** format not in **object**, so you've use `JSON.parse()` to make it object before further processing.

Comment: Did you try with `let obj = JSON.parse(response);`?

Comment: Now i have and it show this error:
´´´
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data[Saber más]
´´´

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you supplied, I would expect these lines to work:

```
const items = response.items;
console.log("items", items);
items.forEach(x => console.log(x.htmlLink));
```

It worked in my test when I set `response` to the JSON you provided. So I would expect `response` is not what you think you it is when this code runs.

```js
const response =  {"kind":"calendar#events","etag":"\"p3288namrojte20g\"","summary":"pedicura","updated":"2019-05-01T14:25:51.642Z","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Cordoba","accessRole":"owner","defaultReminders":[{"method":"popup","minutes":30}],"nextSyncToken":"CJCLqtvE-uECEJCLqtvE-uECGAU=","items":[{"kind":"calendar#event","etag":"\"3113441344690000\"","id":"hb6me2h********1dun5rs10","status":"confirmed","htmlLink":"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=aGI2bWUyaGFvaGtqbWI4bXYxZHVuNXJzMTAgZTYyMXJtMD********Zw","created":"2019-05-01T14:12:08.000Z","updated":"2019-05-01T14:24:32.345Z","summary":"Prueba de: Pedicura en sala 2-x","description":"x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?","creator":{"email":"guit----@gmail.com"},"organizer":{"email":"e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com","displayName":"pedicura","self":true},"start":{"dateTime":"2019-05-08T21:00:00-03:00","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"},"end":{"dateTime":"2019-05-08T23:00:00-03:00","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"},"iCalUID":"hb6me2ha----s10@google.com","sequence":2,"attendees":[{"email":"aleja----it@gmail.com","responseStatus":"needsAction"},{"email":"j----d@gmail.com","responseStatus":"needsAction"}],"reminders":{"useDefault":true}},{"kind":"calendar#event","etag":"\"3113441378884000\"","id":"tv**0nbhkt**47la0k","status":"confirmed","htmlLink":"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dHZmOTQwbmJoa3Q3cnJvYjJsMW00N2xhMGsgZTYyMXJtM*****","created":"2019-05-01T14:18:53.000Z","updated":"2019-05-01T14:24:49.442Z","summary":"Prueba de: Pedicura en sala 2-x","description":"x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?","creator":{"email":"guit----@gmail.com"},"organizer":{"email":"e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com","displayName":"pedicura","self":true},"start":{"dateTime":"2019-05-07T21:00:00-03:00","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"},"end":{"dateTime":"2019-05-07T23:00:00-03:00","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"},"iCalUID":"tvf940nbhk----m47la0k@google.com","sequence":2,"attendees":[{"email":"ale---it@gmail.com","responseStatus":"needsAction"},{"email":"j--d@gmail.com","responseStatus":"needsAction"}],"reminders":{"useDefault":true}},{"kind":"calendar#event","etag":"\"3113441503284000\"","id":"tqhje1kd*****0","status":"confirmed","htmlLink":"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dHFoamUxa2Q0MG51M2Q3cGd2b2xlOGRqODAgZTYyMX*****","created":"2019-05-01T14:25:51.000Z","updated":"2019-05-01T14:25:51.642Z","summary":"Prueba de","description":"x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?","creator":{"email":"guit----@gmail.com"},"organizer":{"email":"e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com","displayName":"prueba","self":true},"start":{"dateTime":"2019-04-26T21:00:00-03:00","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"},"end":{"dateTime":"2019-04-26T23:00:00-03:00","timeZone":"America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"},"iCalUID":"tqh*****7pgvole8dj80@google.com","sequence":0,"attendees":[{"email":"-it@gmail.com","responseStatus":"needsAction"},{"email":"-aud@gmail.com","responseStatus":"needsAction"}],"reminders":{"useDefault":true}}]}
 
const items = response.items;
console.log("items", items);
items.forEach(x => console.log(x.htmlLink));
```

Comment: hello @Karl Galvez, still 

items undefined 
TypeError: items is undefined[Saber más]

Comment: Based on this and your response to @Always Sunny, I feel even more strongly that `response` is not what you expect when trying to use it. Can you `console.log(response)` before trying to use it? Then share the results.

Comment: response is too big; i've uploaded to: https://www.nutrirm.com/response.txt

Comment: @always sunny: i have this error now: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: The response isn't valid JSON. The very first part is invalid, so throwing an error with `result: {â€¦}`. After that, there are still a lot of errors. However, we've determined your issue is in the response, not your code. Hopefully, you have control over the response.

Answer (score 1):

If the response is coming from Promise, you may need to loop on `response.data.items`

Answer (score 1):

I solved, it was on @Always Sunny and on @Karl Galvez way; helped also the @Sandeep P statement because i was on a .then

thank you very much to all who helped and tyed.

Answer (score 0):

// this should work

```
var response = {
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p3288namrojte20g\"",
 "summary": "pedicura",
 "updated": "2019-05-01T14:25:51.642Z",
 "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Cordoba",
 "accessRole": "owner",
 "defaultReminders": [
  {
   "method": "popup",
   "minutes": 30
  }
 ],
 "nextSyncToken": "CJCLqtvE-uECEJCLqtvE-uECGAU=",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3113441344690000\"",
   "id": "hb6me2h********1dun5rs10",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=aGI2bWUyaGFvaGtqbWI4bXYxZHVuNXJzMTAgZTYyMXJtMD********Zw",
   "created": "2019-05-01T14:12:08.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-05-01T14:24:32.345Z",
   "summary": "Prueba de: Pedicura en sala 2-x",
   "description": "x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?",
   "creator": {
    "email": "guit----@gmail.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "pedicura",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-08T21:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-08T23:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "iCalUID": "hb6me2ha----s10@google.com",
   "sequence": 2,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "aleja----it@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    },
    {
     "email": "j----d@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3113441378884000\"",
   "id": "tv**0nbhkt**47la0k",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dHZmOTQwbmJoa3Q3cnJvYjJsMW00N2xhMGsgZTYyMXJtM*****",
   "created": "2019-05-01T14:18:53.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-05-01T14:24:49.442Z",
   "summary": "Prueba de: Pedicura en sala 2-x",
   "description": "x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?",
   "creator": {
    "email": "guit----@gmail.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "pedicura",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-07T21:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-05-07T23:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "iCalUID": "tvf940nbhk----m47la0k@google.com",
   "sequence": 2,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "ale---it@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    },
    {
     "email": "j--d@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3113441503284000\"",
   "id": "tqhje1kd*****0",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dHFoamUxa2Q0MG51M2Q3cGd2b2xlOGRqODAgZTYyMX*****",
   "created": "2019-05-01T14:25:51.000Z",
   "updated": "2019-05-01T14:25:51.642Z",
   "summary": "Prueba de",
   "description": "x-prueba de añadir masajes en sala 2 y notificar al manicura y a otra persona, fernanda?",
   "creator": {
    "email": "guit----@gmail.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "e---s90vak@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "prueba",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2019-04-26T21:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2019-04-26T23:00:00-03:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
   },
   "iCalUID": "tqh*****7pgvole8dj80@google.com",
   "sequence": 0,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "-it@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    },
    {
     "email": "-aud@gmail.com",
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  }
 ]
};
var items = response.items;

if(items) {
    for (var itemsIter = 0; itemsIter < items.length; itemsIter++) {
        var item = items[itemsIter];
        if(item && item.hasOwnProperty('htmlLink')) {
            console.log(item.htmlLink);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello chetan, is not working because i ca't reference "response.items"

Comment: Ok give me sometime will run and give it to you.

Comment: Should work now , find the jsbin here https://jsbin.com/tanileyice/edit?js,console,output